# Limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}:m,n\in{\Bbb N}\right\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let 
$$S=\left\{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}:m,n\in{\Bbb N}\right\}$$
and $S'$ be the set of limit points of $S$. All the results I've found on Google or Math.SE only give the following
$$
\left\{\frac1n:n\geq 1\right\}\cup\{0\}\subset S'. 
$$

Here is my question:
Is
$$
\left\{\frac1n:n\geq 1\right\}\cup\{0\}\supset S'
$$
also true?

Comment: Yes; here's a sketch: Convince yourself the only limit points must be in $[0,1]$. Now pick a point in $[0,1]$. If it's of the form $1/n$ or $0$, then we're done. Otherwise, the point must fall in $(\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k})$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Finally, convince yourself we cannot get arbitrarily close to such a point. (Posted as a comment since many details are omitted.)

Comment: But $S$ contains $2$?

Comment: @Tunococ: according to wikipedia it is demanded that any neighbourhood of the limit point contain a point of the set other than the limit point if that happens to lie in the set (so points like 5/6 etc are also excluded).

Comment: @doetoe Oh you're right. That definition certainly makes more sense in the context of this problem.

Comment: A COMPLETE PROOF IS HERE: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930646/to-find-limit-points-of-the-set-frac1n-frac1m-n-m-1-2-3/1217297#1217297

Answer (score 4):

I think it is. Since we are dealing with a subset of a metrical space, the limit points are real numbers that are the limit of a sequence of elements in that set, unequal to the limit itself.

Such a sequence $(a_i)$ is of the form $({1\over n_i} + {1\over m_i})$, so we have two sequences of natural numbers $(n_i)$ and $(m_i)$ (not uniquely determined by $(a_i)$ but that doesn't matter).

If one of these can get arbitrarily large, say a subsequence of $(n_i)$ goes to infinity, then a subsequence of $(a_i)$ goes to the limit of the corresponding subsequence of the sequence $({1\over m_i})$, which exists, because otherwise the original sequence wouldn't have a limit either. This gives the limit points of the form ${1\over m}$.

If neither grows arbitrarily large, there is only a finite number of possibilities for $a_i = {1\over n_i} + {1\over m_i}$, so the limit must be an element of the sequence, and by definition is not a limit point.